# R for() loop: Pipe 'ls' stdout into read.csv() and create multiple objects

Tags: r, loops, csv, for-loop

I would like to implement an elegant solution: Create objects by proxying `system("ls")` stdout to `read.csv()`, using `for()`.

Working dir:

> ```
> [Data]    #contain 10 .csv files e.g: './Data/dataset01.csv'
>                                               ^-------^(8~16th characters)
> my_Script.Rmd   #RMarkdown script used in the example
> ```

R code:

> ```
> for (i in system("ls ./Data/*.csv"))
>      
>      { read.csv(file=i) -> strsplit(i, 8, 16) }
> ```

What I intented to achieve here:

1. For each filepath stdout from `ls`.
2. Read the .csv file and
3. create a dataframe for each dataset read.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get the filenames.
You can do it as you suggested with `system` but make sure to include `intern=T` to capture the output of the command in as a character string.

```
fl <-system("ls ./MATLAB/*.m", intern = T)
```

Another option is to use the function `list.files`.

```
fl <- list.files(path = "Data", pattern = "\\.csv$", full.names = T)
```

Then use `assign` to assign values to names. Use a combination of `basename` (removes path) and `tools::file_path_sans_ext` (removes file extension).

```
for (i in fl){
  assign(tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(i)), read.csv(i))
}
```

Comment: Cleaner and elegant concept, and most importantly, works like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help. Please accept the answer as a solution ;)